# Call a function when one or more functions has finish

Tags: javascript

I need some help...I have 5 functions in javascript and I'm not able to call the fifth function after previous functions.
I have some like this:

```
function one(){

}
function two(){

}
function three(){

}
function four(){

}
function five(){

}
```

This code, execute the function "five()" before other function. I would like that five() will be execute only after all previous functions have finish.
How can I do that?

EDIT:
This is my call

```
function callFunction(){
    one();
    two();
    three();
    four();
    five();
}
```

Comment: You can use `callback` or `promise`. `Callback` syntax: `one(function(){two();})` and `one` would look like: `function(callback){ // do something... if(callback)callback()}

Comment: your code won't execute any of your functions

Comment: you'll only have the problem you describe if you have asynchronous code

Comment: What is wrong with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/vb500yjy/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is your call ?? Is the process asynchronous ?

else simply call :

```
one();
two();
...
five();
```

**EDIT**

Since they are async functions, you have to execute the next function at the end of the previous async process like that :

```
function one(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    //Do async process
    two();
  }, 1000);
}

function two(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    //Do async process
    three();
  }, 1000);
}

function three(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    // etc...
  }, 1000);
}

one();
```

Comment: The functions are executing one after the other, so the function 5 should be executed the last one after the others have finished the process... But not if one of the functions has async process

Comment: Can you paste the content of your other functions ?

Comment: Check the new answer and accept it if it's working for you :)

Comment: The answer is good, but I think that is not the best solution. Because a function can take 200 millisecond or 2000 millisecond and set a timeout can be a problem.... I'm looking for a solution that is always reliable...

Comment: the "setTimeout" was just an exemple of the async process which is not really the question, the important part of the answer is to launch the next function at the end of the async process, setTimeout or whatever you used... Paste the code inside your functions for a more precise answer

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is to use promises. The promise is great ease of asynchronous processes. You need Promise.all(iterable).

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when
>   all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects
>   with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(function(values) { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

Check this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

If you want IE compatibility you can use q.

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

q also have .all .

I write this example for you:

```
/**
 * Example of Q.all usage
 * @author Georgi Naumov
 * gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and
 * suggestions.
 */
var firstStep = (function () {
    var dfd = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("first step  finished");
        dfd.resolve();
    }, 1000);
    return dfd.promise;
}());

var secondStep = (function () {
    var dfd = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("second step  finished");
        dfd.resolve();
    }, 3000);
    return dfd.promise;
}());

Q.all([firstStep, secondStep]).then(function () {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```

console.log('All done!'); will be executed when all asinc task is finished.

Here is jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/drv4538t/3/

This solution is independent from time interval. Check this example:

```
/**
 * Example of Q.all usage
 * @author Georgi Naumov
 * gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and
 * suggestions.
 */

/**
 * This function is taken from:
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
 */
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var firstStep = (function () {
    var dfd = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("first step  finished");
        dfd.resolve();
    }, getRandomIntInclusive(1000, 10000));
    return dfd.promise;
}());

var secondStep = (function () {
    var dfd = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("second step  finished");
        dfd.resolve();
    }, getRandomIntInclusive(1000, 10000));
    return dfd.promise;
}());

Q.all([firstStep, secondStep]).then(function () {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```

And here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/drv4538t/4/

Comment: I agree, but this will not work with IE [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=promise)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* declare functions */        
function one(){
  two()
}
function two(){
  three()
}
function three(){
   four()
}
function four(){
   five()
}
function five(){

}

/* call function */ 
one()
```

Comment: To call a function you don't use function keyword, you do this only when declare the function.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution can be:

```js
function one(){
  console.log('one')
}
function two(){
  console.log('two')
}
function three(){
  console.log('three')
}
function four(){
  console.log('four')
}
function five(){
  console.log('five')
}

['one','two','three','four','five'].forEach(function(fun){
  window[fun]();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a boolean to true for every function you want to finish before running function 5. Then try to run function 5 at the end of every function...if all functions have finished and function 5 didn't run yet, you run function 5.

```
        var f1Finished = false;
        var f2Finished = false;
        var f3Finished = false;
        var f4Finished = false;
        var ran5 = false;
        function allFinished() {
            return f1Finished && f2Finished && f3Finished && f4Finished;
        }
        function one(){
            f1Finished = true;
            if(allFinished())
                five();
        }
        function two(){
            f2Finished = true;
            if(allFinished())
                five();
        }
        function three(){
            f3Finished = true;
            if(allFinished())
                five();
        }
        function four(){
            f4Finished = true;
            if(allFinished())
                five();
        }
        function five(){
            if(!ran5) {
                ran5 = true;
                //...
            }
        }
        one();
        two();
        three();
        four();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is great article i found that clears the concept of callback function in Jquery.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Sample:

```
function mySandwich(param1, param2, callback) {
alert('Started eating my sandwich.\n\nIt has: ' + param1 + ', ' + param2);
callback();}

mySandwich('ham', 'cheese', function() {
    alert('Finished eating my sandwich.');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would do it

```
function callFunction(){
    one();
    Await();
    two();
    Await();
    three();
    Await();
    four();
    Await();
    five();
}

function Await(){
for(var i=0;i<100000;i++){
}

}
```

You can also fine tune the wait funtion

Comment: omg this is so ugly... You're not even sure that the process will be completed before executing the next function